Use email attribute from Contacts. Not Working in marketing cloud
We have a journey with multiple eDM activities in it. Our subscriber often change their email addresses and this journey will run for a long duration of time. To facilitate this email address change we are using the option of Use "email attribute from Contacts" so that whenever the email is changed the next eDM is delivered on the updated email to our subscribers. However, we have observed that emails were not sent out using this option. please help up with below issue:

Identifying why email is not sent even though we have added this DE to the contact attribute group

How do we facilitate the email address change for our customers in the running journeys?


The journey is fired via API

Do you have an automation to update the email address change to All Subscribers List for these subscribers?

No, This journey is fired through an API event on a form submit from external website, Hence automation may not help, we want our use case to be real time.

I mean the automation is a separate one. It will update the email address change to All Subscribers List, hence, in the next email send during the journey, the journey can use the updated email address for the contact.

The email attribute from Contacts is going to pick the Email Address saved in All Subscribers.
This email is only updated is only updated when you send an email to this Subscriber Key using the EmailAddress of the Entry Source and it differs from the one saved in All Subscribers; changes in Sales Cloud won't automatically update the list (source)
Therefore, you need to have a process to manually update All Subscribers so that the journeys pick the new email, or else it will always default to the last email address used to send an email to each contact.
Hope that helps!
